# Перевести пример кода c# на js

Tags: javascript, c#

Стремлюсь узнать как этот же код на c# написать на js. Я закомментил все что должно быть переведено в код на js.
Надеюсь сообществу и мне будет полезно знать как правильно реализовать полноценный класс.

```
public class Men // класс
{
    public string Name { get; set; } // публичное свойство

    private int Age; // приватное поле

    public Men(string Name) // конструктор
    {
        this.Name = Name; // заполнение поля объекта
    }

    public void SayHi() // публичный метод
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hi"); // это можно не писать
        Men men = new Men("Alex"); // создание экземпляра класса самого себя
    }
}
```

Comment: А что у вас получилось на JS? Вы покажите, а мы исправим ошибки

Comment: покажите пример того что вы пробовали писать на js. + в js, есть два подхода, на старых prototype, и новый вариант с ключевым словом class.

Comment: @test123 суть вопроса в том чтобы указать принцип того как это реализовывается на js. Так сказать дать удочку, а не рыбку. Этот код на c# абстрактный, на js е я пишу другой объект: 
`var Sprite = function (x) {
    this.x = null; // определение (не инициализация) переменной
    this.privateSetX = function () {
        this.x = x; 
}
}`

Comment: Я в js пытаюсь создать класс через конструктор, но в этом случае везде и всю надо писать this., их просто тьма как много

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Приватных полей нет](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/622463/178988), всё публичное. В остальном (при использовании ES5) так:

```js
var Man = (function () {
  function Man(name) {
    console.log("Creating " + name);
    this.name = name;
  }

  Man.prototype.sayHi = function () {
    console.log("Hi from " + this.name);
    var man = new Man("Alex");
  };
  
  return Man;
})();

var x = new Man("Abc");
x.sayHi();
```

Comment: `var man = new Man("Alex");` - ??

Comment: @Igor, смотри код в вопросе. Просили _`Men men = new Men("Alex"); // создание экземпляра класса самого себя`_ - сделал. Что не так?

Comment: а, да. Какая-то бессмысленная строка. (Минус не мой.)

Comment: В глобальном контексте выполнения (за пределами каких-либо функций), `this` ссылается на глобальный объект вне зависимости от использования в строгом или нестрогом режиме. И того, приватность есть - так как область функции локальная, объекту `window` до этого нет дела, следовательно, переменная определенная через `let, var, const` в блоке `function` будет приватным и `this` будет уже ссылаться на текущую локальность.

Comment: @And 1. Зачем ты мне рассказал про this, я вообще не понял. 2. Приватность через переменные в замыкании исключает помещение методов в прототип и описана [в одном из ответов](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/630291/178988) по ссылке. Но более идиоматическим решением является отказ от приватности, а не от методов в прототипе. И вообще, все варианты расписаны там же в [моём ответе](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/631589/178988).

Answer (score 1):

Пример на старых prototype:

```
var Men = function(name, age) {
    this.name = name;
    if(age!=null && !(age==='undefined'))
        this.age = age;
};

Men.prototype.name = null;

Men.prototype.SayHi = function(){
    console.log("Hi " + this.name + " [you age "+this.age+"]");
};
```

Создание и вызов:

```
let instance1 = new Men("Вася",24);
instance1.SayHi();

let instance2 = new Men("Петя");
instance2.SayHi();
```

Comment: Я так и делал, если метод 10 и более строк и он сильносвязанный (т.е. обращается к другим методам и полям этого же класса), то все заполняется this. - ами как в Men.prototype.SayHi. Думал, может есть способ полаконичнее

Comment: @AleksandrSergeevich, это не шарп, логично что тут есть свой синтаксис, и он подрузомевает что вы указываете откуда именно хотите взять поле, если вы не возьмёте this, то даже в случае с классом - это походит на дурную практику, когда на месте age, может запросто оказаться глобальная переменная а не поле класса Men. Как вы предлагаете разруливать такую ситуацию?

Answer (score 0):

Например так:

```
var men = (name) => {
    if(!name) {
        return null;
    }
    var privateName = 'Alex';
    class Men {
        constructor(name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        getPrivateName() {
            return privateName;
        }
        getPublicName() {
            return this.name;
        }
    }
    return new Men(name);
}, run = men('Lex');
```

Так:

```
function Men(name) {
    if (!name) {
        return null;
    }
    var privateName = 'Alex';
    this.name = name;
    this.getPrivateName = function () {
        return privateName;
    };
    this.getPublicName = function () {
        return this.name;
    };
    return this;
}
run = new Men('Lex');
```

Или так:

```
var Men = function (name) {
    if (!name) {
        return null;
    }
    var privateName = 'Alex';
    this.name = name;
    this.getPrivateName = function () {
        return privateName;
    };
    this.getPublicName = function () {
        return this.name;
    };
    return this;
}, run = Men('Lex');
```

Дадут одинаковый результат:

```
console.log(run.getPrivateName(), run.getPublicName(), run.name, run.privateName); 
// Alex Lex Lex undefined
```

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что тут создается не класс, а функция men, а когда мы делаем так: `run = men('Lex');`  мы вызываем функцию men, которая возвращает класс Men?  Если это так, то до меня недоходит как privateName не остается локальной переменной функции и передается в переменную run вместе с объектом Men...

Comment: @AleksandrSergeevich, тут создается объект, анонимной стрелочной функции, а в ее локальной области видимости создается переменная `privateName` и класс `Men` с публичными свойствами.

Comment: `run = Men('Lex');` - что есть `this` внутри `Men`? и чему равно `run`?

Comment: @Igor, Оно есть объект внутри функции.

Comment: @And Оно есть `window`, как и `run`.

Comment: @Igor, В большинстве случаев значение `this` определяется тем, каким образом вызвана функция. Мы даже сможем внутри `var obj = {n=1, f:()=>{return this.n;}}` хотя если будет еще один вложенный объект, `this` станет вложенным и изменится в зависимости от вложенности `function`.